# Google Maps API V3 - updated satellite imagery -> polygons displaced | Solution? Overlay/CustomMapTypes?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polygon, satellite-image

I hope to find a solution for my problem! Many thanks in advance for help and advices.

My problem: My Script loads 100-200 polygons (KML/KMZ file) into a Google Maps Map with satellite imagery as MapType.(I use Google Maps API V3).

I creat the polygons with the help of Google Earth Pro by exporting them into a KML/KMZ file.

Until now there was no problem and my solution worked fine. But Google updated the satellite imagery in the area of my interest. For that reason all my polygons are now displaced.

A catastrophe! Disaster beyond all expectations...

At least I have access to the old/"historical" imagery via Google Earth (Pro). Is there a possibilty to get access to the old imagery via Google Maps API?

**Unitl now I tried the following solutions/alternatives:**

1. I measured the "update-shift" in decimal grades via Google Earth Pro and changed the coordinates in the KML files with a Pearl script = > The new satellite imagery has a higher resolution, some polygons are still shifted or the structure/form doesn´t match.
2. I also tried to export the historical imagery via Google Earth Pro as JPEG (6MB) to load the file as an overlay into my Google Maps Map => The polygons match but the load time is about 2-3min and the quality isn´t really good so that I have to restrict the maxZoomlevel.
3. Last but not least I tried to create a customized basic tilemap with the MapTypeBus and ImageMapTiles. (100 tiles, 700MB) => The load time is unbearable and the tiles cover my polygons.

Has anybode a corresponding idea? Any solution? Is there a possibilty ot get access to old satellite imagery via Google Maps API in referring to Google Earth?

Many many thanks in advance!

Best regards

DrMcKay

Comment: I think there is no official service to retrieve old satellite images. See this topic.
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-maps-api/kzqwzRgxkow

Comment: If the new tiles are misaligned you could report the issue, it might get fixed.